# How to configure an I2c Controller in the PS of the Zynq 7000 as a slave from Linux

Tags: linux, driver, yocto, i2c, xilinx

I am using a zed board with a Zynq 7000 on it. The end goal is to have the I2c-0 controller in the physical PS of the Zynq7000 to act as an I2c slave device.

I am using yocto/bitbake to generate linux images for my device. So far, I have been able to map my I2c-0 device SDA and SCK lines to physical pins on the zed board. I have overwritten the zynq-7000.dtsi with my own device tree to enable the i2c0 device.

From the linux shell of my board, I can see the i2c device with "i2cdetect -l" which gives the following output:

```
root@zed-board:~# i2cdetect -l
i2c-0   i2c             Cadence I2C at e0004000                 I2C adapter
```

From a simple hello.c program I can use

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/i2c.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
```

to write data with the i2c master and I can see the data coming out of my pins.

However, I have no idea how to configure this device as a slave. I can see from the cadence i2c driver code https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-cadence.c
that slave mode is supported. I just don't know what i need to do so that from a user space application I can put the device into slave mode and register the callbacks for slave events.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need to enable slave mode in DTS and then tell what will be the device backed by this slave address. Means you need a driver for the emulation. So far Linux kernel has only EEPROM driver present.

Comment: How do i enable slave mode in dts?